# "Unclean server" connections not being cleaned up

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I have an application connecting to a PostgreSQL server via PgBouncer, all running in Kubernetes. Every couple of minutes, the PgBouncer process seems to crash, and Kubernetes restarts it. Just before PgBouncer crashes, I see the following in the logs:

```
2018-05-29 17:44:59.897 1 LOG S-0xe09d60: my_user/my_database@10.201.0.49:5432 closing because: unclean server (age=112)
```

Looking at `pg_stat_activity` after PgBouncer has restarted, I still see old connections from the old PgBouncer process that seem to be hanging around waiting on locks.

1. What is an unclean connection, and why does PgBouncer crash when closing them?
2. Should I expect to see connections from old processes remaining in `pg_stat_activity`? What's the best way of cleaning these up?